# In Java, how to distinguish classes that implement the same interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Say we have the following interface:

```
interface Addable {
    Addable add (Addable element);
}
```

Now I want to declare two classes, say `MyList` and `MyArray` that implement the above interface. How can I do this, but prevent a `MyArray` object being added to a `MyList` and vice versa?

Is there a way to do this without an `if` statement and `instanceof`?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without `if` and `instanceof`?

Comment: Don't use a common interface if the implementation is not exchangeable!

Comment: What is `add` supposed to return? What are you supposed to be able to add to a `MyArray` for example? Only other `MyArray`s?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern is designated for differentiation of different implementations of one interface. But I don't think this exact situation is suitable for it, I agree with @codesparkle here.

Answer (score 5):

```
interface Addable<T extends Addable<T>> {
    T add (T element);
}

class MyList  implements Addable<MyList> {
    public MyList add(MyList element) {
        return null;
    }
}

class MyArray   implements Addable<MyArray> {
    public MyArray add(MyArray element) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Just be aware that `class SillyList implements Addable<MyArray>` is possible.

Answer (score 4):

How about changing your interface definition to the following:

```
    interface Addable<T extends Addable.Element> {
        interface Element { }

        Element add(T element); // OR T add(T element);
    }

    class MyList implements Addable<MyList.MyListElement> {

        static class MyListElement implements Addable.Element { }

        @Override
        public Element add(MyListElement element) {
            return null;
        }
    }


    class MyArray implements Addable<MyArray.MyArrayElement> {
        static class MyArrayElement implements Addable.Element { }

        @Override
        public Element add(MyArrayElement element) {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        MyArray myArray = new MyArray();
        MyArrayElement a = new MyArrayElement();
        myArray.add(a);

        MyList myList = new MyList();
        MyListElement l = new MyListElement();
        myList.add(l);

        //try to add a MyArrayElement to a MyList
        // Error The method add(MyListElement) in the type MyList
        // is not applicable for the arguments (MyArrayElement)
        myList.add(e);

        //try to add a MyListElement to a MyArray
        // Error The method add(MyArrayElement) in the type MyArray
        // is not applicable for the arguments (MyListElement)
        myArray.add(l);
    }
```

The [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) quoted below explains why this works:

> Generics are a facility of generic programming that was added to the
>   Java programming language in 2004 as part of J2SE 5.0. They allow "a
>   type or method to operate on objects of various types while providing
>   compile-time type safety."[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) A common use of this feature is when
>   using a Java Collection that can hold objects of any type, to specify
>   the specific type of object stored in it.

Comment: @SoboLAN - You need to go to the Java Tutorial and read the section on generic types.  That will help you understand why it works.

Comment: @StephenC I do know why it works. I meant an explanation for other people that may read this. After all, it's a very public place...

Comment: @SoboLAN Answer updated to address your comments and provide an example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to learn about **Java Generics**.

Q: How do you prevent this for a Java `ArrayList`?

A: By using `ArrayList<MyArray>` vs. `ArrayList<MyList>`.

That is the *same* thing you want to have here:

```
interface Addable<T> {
    T add (T element);
}
```

And then have your classes implement `Addable<MyList>` and `Addable<MyArray>`.

For MyList you then have to implement the method

```
MyList add(MyList element);
```

while for MyArray it will look like this:

```
MyArray add(MyArray element);
```

As you can see, you can not add a MyList to a MyArray, or the other way round.